# Pieces of the past quest won't start

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-one

I found the shards of Mehrunes' Razor before starting the Pieces of the Past quest, and just now went to Dawnstar to start the quest, nobody has died, and Silus was talking to someone in front of his house before I got there, and then proceeded to head inside. I followed him in and he talked about the items in his house, but he was sitting on the chair next to his bed while doing so... I talked to him after he was done, and he wouldn't trigger the quest... What do I do?

Comment: What level are you? You need to be level 20.

Comment: If I recall correctly, I was at lvl 60 or so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... Loaded my save from before I met Jarl Balgruuf, and decided to head back there once I got to lvl 30 or so, and turns out it glitched when I first made the save... I had mods on that allowed me to level up my skills and therefore my lvl rather quickly, as well as a mod that enables fast travel to all main-quest-related places, so that may have ruined it... oh well, guess I have to cheat room it... Wanted to actually do the quest for it, but I guess I won't be able to...